# How can I modify this code to allow my client socket program to send a string to the server?

Tags: java, string, sockets, inputstream, outputstream

Hi ive written some code to connect to a server through the use of a socket. Id like to write some simple code that allows me to send a string to the server, im assuming this will involve input and output streams but I am new to this. Ive put the code I am working with below, any insights into the best way to accomplish this would be great.

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class SocketMarket
{
   public static void main(String [] args)
   {
      String serverName = "XX.X.X.XXX";
      int port = XXXX;

      try
      {
         System.out.println("Connecting to " + serverName + " on port " + port);
         Socket client = new Socket(serverName, port);

         System.out.println("Connected to " + client.getRemoteSocketAddress());        
      }

      catch(IOException e)
      {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }       
   }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
client.getOutputStream().write("Hello World".getBytes());
client.getOutputStream().flush();
```

The above is how you would send just a `String`, but you will probably want to build up some infrastructure around sending arbitrary text.

The general idea is that your server and client will communicate with each other using `InputStream`'s and `OutputStream`'s, which can be accessed from a [`Socket`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html) via `getInputStream()` and `getOutputStream()`, once the connection between them is made.

For your server to receive connections, you should be using a [`ServerSocket`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html) to `accept()` incoming connections.

Comment: When using the input and output streams do I need to instantiate them or can I call them freely as long as the socket is connected to the server?

Comment: You will not instantiate them.  Once a `Socket` connection is established, the `InputStream`/`OutputStream`'s will be open and ready to send (and receive) data across.  The JavaDoc provided in the answer should give more insight into what conditions cause the streams to close.

Answer (score 0):

Insight is here, the "really big index" for java.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/readingWriting.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it involves `OutputStream`s. If you want to output `String`s you could write raw bytes via the `OutputStream` you get from the connection but then you completely loose control over encoding. You need to learn about reader/writer/streams first, then networking via sockets is simple. You can find the relevant part of the Java tutorials here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/ (you can ignore the NIO part completely for the beginning). After that you can learn about socket networking: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/index.html .